# Convert a nested list from [[...],[...]] to [(...),(...)]

Tags: python

Convert a nested list from [[...],[...]] to [(...),(...)]. I wish to format my list below :

```
x=[['dog', 2], ['bird', 1],['dog',1]]
```

to

```
x=[('dog', 3), ('bird', 1)]
```

Here is my code for reference.

```
#Convert last element of nested list to int
newlist = [[int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in sub for sub in x]

#add the 2 columns that match 
grouped = dict()
grouped.update((name,grouped.get(name,0)+value) for name,value in newlist)
x = [*map(list,grouped.items())]
```

Could this be due to my use of a dict()

I have been successful with adding the second indices given that the first ones match, however the result is being formatted as such

```
x=[['dog', 3], ['bird', 1]]
```

however, I would like it as so any advice on how to get this ideal output?

```
x=[('dog', 3), ('bird', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

x=[['dog', 2], ['bird', 1],['dog',1]]


c = Counter()

for k, v in x:
    c[k] += v

print(c)

# as pointed out by wim in the comments, use the below
# to get a list of tuples:

print([*c.items()])
```

Comment: And `[*c.items()]` for the output desired in the question (list of tuples)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do so:

```
x = [['dog', 2], ['bird', 1], ['dog', 1]]

data = {k: 0 for k, _ in x}
for key, num in x:
    data[key] += num
print(list(data.items()))  # [('dog', 3), ('bird', 1)]
```

---

You can also use `setdefault()`:

```
data = {}
for key, num in x:
    data.setdefault(key, 0)
    data[key] += num
print(list(data.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like this works

```
newlist = [int(element) if element[0].isdigit() else element for element in [sub for sub in x]]

# add the 2 columns that match
grouped = dict()
grouped.update((name, grouped.get(name, 0) + value) for name, value in newlist)
x = [*map(tuple, grouped.items())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it a `list` in the first place. The only real thing to note here is replacing `list` with `tuple` however, I also removed the unpacking ([*...]) and went directly to casting the parent as a `list`.

change:
`x = [*map(list,grouped.items())]`

to:
`x = list(map(tuple, grouped.items()))`

Answer (score -2):

```
x=[['dog', 3], ['bird', 1]]
# You want it to be...
x=[('dog', 3), ('bird', 1)]
```

---

So you should first know how to convert `['dog', 3]` to `('dog', 3)`:

```
>>> x = ['dog', 3]
>>> tuple(x)
('dog', 3)
```

To make it a `tuple` you just have to use the `tuple`'s `class` constructor.

---

Then you have to apply this to the whole `x` `list`:

```
x = [tuple(i) for i in x]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything to sum the common items.

Comment: Right, I was just providing an information about the casting. But the OP is asking for the conversion of the result from lists to tuples, so what's the problem?

Comment: You should check out the question again. They are asking how to convert a list with a variable number of `["dog", n]` for example and sum those n's into a single tuple.

Comment: "however, I would like it as so any advice on how to get this ideal output?" I was trying to help for this problem.